# FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

Below is the error which i'm getting after trying to install the app. The app was developed a couple of months ago, now i wanted to update it, but i'm unable to install it again.

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'.
> There were multiple failures while executing work items
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
      > Failed to process: /Users/vivekrk/Desktop/WeatherMonitor/android/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
      > Failed to process: /Users/vivekrk/Desktop/WeatherMonitor/android/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got same error a couple of days back, seems you've got to enable multidex to true and delete the build folder.

Go to android/app/build.gradle and add the line multiDexEnabled true and set minSdkVersion to 21 inside defaultConfig like this

```
...
android{
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  ...
}
...
```

You can check this thread out on react-native

1. https://github.com/oney/react-native-gcm-android/issues/32
2. https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1344

Comment: Didn't work, again the same error